# Animating transparency in Three JS

Tags: three.js, blender

I am currently working on a project where I have a main object in my browser and with a couple of animations that make text "appear".

I have created this in a blender project and using Alpha Hashed blend mode and set the Alpha property to 0 at keyframe 0 and move it to alpha 1 at the end keyframe.

When rendering the animations in Blender I get the expected result, but once exported into an .glb file and loading it in Three.Js the alpha property doesn't get updated.

For some debugging functionality I added some small movement to the text mesh and that is working correctly.

I have also tried the model on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/, with the same result. The text animation movement animation is working, but the text is always at alpha 1.

It did give an error, but I can't seem to debug it and I am not sure if this has anything todo with the animation for the text:

ACCESSOR_VECTOR3_NON_UNIT   Vector3 at accessor indices 2688..2690 is not of unit length: 0.    /meshes/14/primitives/0/attributes/NORMAL

Unfortunately I can't share the model. Thanks in advance for helping out!

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing the ACCESSOR_VECTOR3_NON_UNIT error?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure this one out. What I ended up doing was programmatically toggling the visibility of the meshes directly that I was trying to hide with the animation. This way it didn't look as fancy with a face, but it got the job done.

Comment: I eventually discovered an export warning after launching Blender from the command line: "WARNING: Could not calculate tangents. Please try to triangulate the mesh first." I added a Triangulate modier to the offending mesh and that did the trick. Not sure how the other error from the glTF Validator was related.